# Wordpress (Search Icon on Menu Bar)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Anyone know how to add a search icon only on a menu bar? It will looks something like that from this website http://www.preciousmitre.com/

I want to add that search icon from that website to my website which is https://xyzshopping.000webhostapp.com/ please help me and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**For Custom Themes**

---

If you're only going to use it on the menu you can do so by creating a file called searchform.php and placing it on the main directory of the theme. WordPress looks for that file before generating the default HTML5 form which looks like this:

`<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?></span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field"
            placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search …', 'placeholder' ) ?>"
            value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s"
            title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit"
        value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) ?>" />
</form>`

Once you have a form built (make sure to use the same attributes) you can then call it on your header.php or wherever file you have your menu on by using the WordPress function `get_search_form()` [link to function reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/)

EDIT:
In order to make the form show up when you click the search button you have to create a button on your menu that opens the form text input.

**For Downloaded Themes**

---

You can use a plug in called "[Add Search to Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-search-to-menu/)". What this does is allow you to add the search form to the menu and it also gives you some visual options as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help bro ! Would you mind list out the step for me to do it ? I'm newbie in wordpress and I don't know how to do it . Thanks !

Comment: @Aurora, are you building a theme or did you download a theme from somewhere?

Comment: Nope, I'm using a downloaded theme for my website which is Optimizer

Comment: @Aurora, I've added the answer to your question.

Comment: thanks bro, the search icon did display on my menu header, but when I click on the search button, the search box is not aligned properly. Do you know how to make the search box aligned properly according to my website ? Thanks! Below is the screenshot of the issues.

http://imgur.com/a/zNm41

Comment: @Aurora, just use CSS to fix it. Most themes allow you to add extra code on the css so just do that.